# Unresolved external symbol globalThreadCount when trying to compile a project including openexr

Tags: c++, linker, unresolved-external, openexr

I've cloned the [pbrt-v3 repository](https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3) using Visual Studio 2017. I've tried to compile a project where I included the Transform.h, but I'm getting the following error from the linker:

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl Imf::globalThreadCount(void)" (?globalThreadCount@Imf@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "class pbrt::RGBSpectrum * __cdecl pbrt::ReadImageEXR(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int *,int *,class pbrt::Bounds2 *,class pbrt::Bounds2 *)" (?ReadImageEXR@pbrt@@YAPEAVRGBSpectrum@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PEAH1PEAV?$Bounds2@H@1@2@Z)

I've compiled and installed openexr using CMake for Visual Studio. I've added

libpbrt.lib
libglog_static.lib
IlmThread-2_2.lib
Half.lib
Iex-2_2.lib
IexMath-2_2.lib
Imath-2_2.lib

as additional dependencies in the project settings. I wasn't able to figure out in which library `globalThreadCount` is defined. So, which library am I missing?

Comment: The `globalThreadCount` comes from ilmimf (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/free-image/+/71163caf89862f79f6419077cf6f0b18b7725d52/Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfThreading.h) .

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis So, shouldn't IlmThread-2_2.lib be the right library?